# Programming a Shrinking Cube in Unity. No Errors but no Visible Changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

So I'm new to unity and trying to create a cube programmatically at the start, and when you press the down arrow key it decrements gradually.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LetThereBeLight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject rubixCube;
    public Vector3 newScale;
    public Vector3 currentScale;`

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject rubixCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        rubixCube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(10f, 10f, 10f);
        rubixCube.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        currentScale = rubixCube.transform.localScale;
        newScale = new Vector3(-1f, -1f, -1f);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)){

            currentScale += newScale;

            if(currentScale.x < 10){
                print("Well at least this worked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the play button in unity, the cube is created and I receive no errors but the cube does not shrink when I press the down arrow key. However, I know that the size of the vector is decrementing because I tell it to print a message as a test and it does so. But there are no visible changes to the size of the cube in the viewer.

Also, I originally put

`currentScale = rubixCube.transform.localScale;` in the `void Update()` function rather than the `void Start()` and it gave me an error `Unassigned reference exception: The variable rubixCube of LetThereBeLight has not been assigned` but shouldn't it not matter what function it is in whether it is called upon start or looped over because I already made `rubixCube` a public GameObject outside of both functions?

Does anyone know how to solve this? Why doesn't this script work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You declare your cube locally. Therefore there is no reference elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. In the `Start` you do

   ```
   GameObject rubixCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
   ```

   which creates a local variable and hides the class field with equal name `rubixCube`!

   => The class field `rubixCube` you later try to use in `Update` is never assigned!

   In `Start` it should rather simply be

   ```
   rubixCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
   ```
2. Then in `Update` you do

   ```
    currentScale += newScale;
   ```

   You are changing the field `currentScale`, which is a `Vector3` value ... but that is all.

   You are not actually changing the `Transform` component on the `GameObject` itself at all, so the cube in your game is not actually being affected at all by this code.

   You rather have to actually assign something back to the **property**

   ```
   currentScale += newScale;
   rubixCube.transform.localScale = currentScale;
   ```

Comment: I edited your answer a bit to make it complete. Also note that for this it doesn't really matter at all that `Vector3` is a struct or class .. what matters is that `Transform.localScale` is a **property** and unless you assign something to it, it's setter is never called which then handles the actual assignment in the underlying c++ layer

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify your code, I searched for information, and clicked the "CreaterubixCube" button in the OnGUI() function to call the "CreatePrimitive" method, thereby creating a rubixCub object and adding its position attribute. I also just learned unity3d.

[image]